# How to prevent the page from getting redirected on inserting record

Tags: apex, soql

I have a very simple code to add a record to a custom object. The code is adding the record perfectly fine. However, when I click the command button, it adds the record but also redirects my screen to the added record. I have put the `setRedirect(false)` condition. I am puzzled here. Please help!

```
    public PageReference save2() { 
    Sales_Rep_Goal__c cd = new Sales_Rep_Goal__c();
    cd.Sales_Rep1__c = cds.Sales_Rep1__c;
    cd.Year__c = cds.Year__c;
    cd.Month__c = cds.Month__c;
    cd.Rental_Goal__c = cds.Rental_Goal__c;
    insert cd;
    Pagereference pg = new Pagereference('/' + cd.id);
    pg.setRedirect(false);
    return pg;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

setRedirect will still change the page you are navigating to even if it is false, it just won't change the view state. In your case since you are navigating to a standard page, to a user it basically has the same implementation as a redirection.

> This type of redirect performs an HTTP GET request, and flushes the
>   view state, which uses POST. If set to false, the redirect is a
>   server-side forward that preserves the view state if and only if the
>   target page uses the same controller and contains the proper subset of
>   extensions used by the source page.

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_System_PageReference_setRedirect.htm

If you don't want to redirect at all, just **return null** to stay on the page.

Comment: Thanks Michael. return null worked fine. a little additional help. So through this code, I have created an `Add` button. I also want to keep `delete` button on the page, which would delete the record based on values in input fields.. Can you tell me how can I go about it

Comment: You may want to post that as a separate question as it is different from the original question. That will ensure other people searching for the same question in the future are able to find it :)

Comment: done. I have posted the question here. If you have time it will be great if you can help me with that. :) http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/28586/adding-delete-button-to-vf-page

Answer (score 1):

It still change page  when you return PageReference. It pretty standard behavior. Solution for you is just returning `null` value - this is usual answer for your question.

But If I may, won't be better to simply change this method to void?