# Adding Delete button to VF page

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql

I have an `Add` button to insert the values from Input fields to Custom objects. I also want to keep `delete` button to delete the last added record. How can I add this delete button? Following is the code for adding the records:

```
    public PageReference save2() { 
    Sales_Rep_Goal__c cd = new Sales_Rep_Goal__c();
    cd.Sales_Rep1__c = cds.Sales_Rep1__c;
    cd.Year__c = cds.Year__c;
    cd.Month__c = cds.Month__c;
    cd.Rental_Goal__c = cds.Rental_Goal__c;
    insert cd;
    Pagereference pg = new Pagereference('/' + cd.id);
    pg.setRedirect(false);
    return null;
}
```

Please help.

Comment: Same as the functionality of adding record, of which answer i have provided in you previous question. Only difference of DML operation and logic in method. @Robin

Comment: That depends - you need custom delete functionality? Or those from standard controller? By last you mean - last added by VF page or last added to database?

Comment: last added by VF page. Basically the values in input fields would point to the added record. I want to give user an option even to delete it, in case of any mistake while adding the values.

Answer (score 1):

As @regal mentioned, it is simply a custom method that you expose with an <apex:commandButton> similar to how you are doing the add.

In your Apex code, as part of your insert you'll want to set a class level variable to keep track of the most recent creation.

**Apex**

```
public class TestClass
{
    public Sales_Rep_Goal__c lastGoal {get; private set;}

    public void save2()
    {
        Sales_Rep_Goal__c cd = new Sales_Rep_Goal__c();
        cd.Sales_Rep1__c = cds.Sales_Rep1__c;
        cd.Year__c = cds.Year__c;
        cd.Month__c = cds.Month__c;
        cd.Rental_Goal__c = cds.Rental_Goal__c;
        insert cd;

        lastGoal = cd
    }

    public void deleteLast()
    {
        delete lastGoal;
    }
}
```

**Visualforce**

```
<apex:commandButton value="Delete Last" action="{!deleteLast}" rendered="{!lastGoal != null}"/>
```